# How to specifically set the delay of .ondblclick to 3 seconds in JS/HTML

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html lang = "en">
  <head>
    <title> Visibility control </title>
    <meta charset = "utf-8" />
    <script type = "text/javascript"  src = "showHide.js" >
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action = "">
      <div id = "saturn"  style = "position: relative; 
           visibility: visible;">
        <img src = "../images/saturn.png" 
             alt = "(Pictures of Saturn)" />
      </div>
      <p>
        <br />
        <input type = "button"  value = "Show/Hide"
               onclick = "ShowIMG()"; ondblclick = "HideIMG()" />
      </p>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the html part. What What I've done here is when the user clicks the button once, a showIMG function is called to show the image. When the user clicks it twice within 3 seconds the hideIMG function is called and the image disappears instead.

```
function ShowIMG() 
{
    dom = document.getElementById("saturn").style;  

    if (dom.visibility == "hidden")
    {
        dom.visibility = "visible";
    }
}

function HideIMG()
{
    dom = document.getElementById("saturn").style;

    if (dom.visibility == "visible")
    {
        dom.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}
```

These are the functions that are called. Is there a way to set the delay of .ondblclick or can I add a timer of some sort?

I also believe the default delay is half a second if I remember correctly.

Comment: Why double click to hide? It doesn't seem very intuitive. Why not click once to show, click again to hide?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
function HideIMG()
{
    var theDelay = 3000;
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        dom = document.getElementById("saturn").style;
        if (dom.visibility == "visible")
        {
            dom.visibility = "hidden";
        }
    }, theDelay);
}
```

Comment: ondblclick seems to be calling onclick first so nothing is happening.